# Populating a drop down list dynamically in ASP.net, and passing that value to another query?

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, data-driven, population

2 questions for everybody.

1) How can I order the years by their value, it crashes when I use DESC?

2) If I populate my list like so:

```
 string strConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["rde_410978ConnectionString"].ToString();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConn);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "Select Distinct Year from MonthlySales DESC"; //DESC DOESNT WORK?

    DataSet objDs = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter dAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    dAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
    con.Open();
    dAdapter.Fill(objDs);
    con.Close();

    if (objDs.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        ddItems.DataSource = objDs.Tables[0];
        ddItems.DataTextField = "Year";
        ddItems.DataValueField = "Year";
        ddItems.DataBind();
        ddItems.Items.Insert(0, "Select");
    }
```

How can I make the year selected appear under ddItems.SelectedItem?

```
WHERE Year = " + ddItems.SelectedItem + "GROUP BY Name ";
```

That part of another query doesn't work when I populate my list dynamically, any reasons why/ how can I fix it.

Regards.

EDIT:
To make my second question clearer, after debugging its always selecting the top item in the drop down list not the actual selected item?

Comment: I didn't really get your second part/question of the post... Can you please elaborate a little more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in your sql you are missing "order by"...use this

```
"Select Distinct Year from MonthlySales order by Year DESC"
```

Second, you need to make use of the SelectedValue property to get your dropdown's selected value...as below...

```
WHERE Year = " + ddItems.SelectedValue + " GROUP BY Name";
```

Having said that, I strongly recommend you to use..."parameterized" sql...Here is an example on how you could enable parameterized sql query...
[Give me parameterized SQL, or give me death](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)

**Update:**

Looks like you are binding your dropdown on every post back...you may try this...

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack && objDs.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        ddItems.DataSource = objDs.Tables[0];
        ddItems.DataTextField = "Year";
        ddItems.DataValueField = "Year";
        ddItems.DataBind();
        ddItems.Items.Insert(0, "Select");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, for some reason its always getting the top value in the dropdownlist, no matter what is selected?

Comment: Please provide space in `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1):

Ans 1)

```
cmd.CommandText = "Select Distinct Year from MonthlySales ORDER BY 1 DESC"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `order by`. Here it is.

```
"Select Distinct Year from MonthlySales order by Year DESC";
```

For your second part you can do this. Please mind the space in `" GROUP BY Name"`

```
WHERE Year = " + ddItems.SelectedItem.Text + " GROUP BY Name ";
```

Comment: @Lewis Elliott: In you Page_Load event bind your DropDownList in `if(!IsPostBack)`. It seems that you are not using it right now that's why every time it get rebind.

Answer (score 1):

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConn))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "Select Distinct Year from MonthlySales Order By DESC";

        using (DataSet objDs = new DataSet())
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter dAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                dAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
                con.Open();
                dAdapter.Fill(objDs);
                con.Close();

                if (objDs.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    ddItems.DataSource = objDs.Tables[0];
                    ddItems.DataTextField = "Year";
                    ddItems.DataValueField = "Year";
                    ddItems.DataBind();
                    ddItems.Items.Insert(0, "Select");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```